# Positive and negative value sum separately in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Find and sum all negative values
Find and sum all positive values

**DATA**

```
ID   value

A    -1
B    -5
AA    1
TT    3
UV    4
QA    50
WQ   -40
QC    10
```

**DESIRED**

```
positive  68

negative -46
```

**DOING**

```
df.groupby(df['value'].agg([('value' , lambda x : x[x < 0].sum()) , ('positive' , lambda x : x[x > 0].sum())])
```

Any suggestion is appreciated

Comment: Okay, so **what happens** when you try your attempt? "Any suggestion is appreciated" is [not a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236). Are you asking us how to do it? Are you asking what's wrong with the existing code? Something else?

Comment: awesome suggestion will update  @KarlKnechtel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you have to make a dataframe of your data using pandas.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'ID': ['A', 'B', 'AA', 'TT', 'UV', 'QA', 'WQ', 'QC'],
                   'value': [-1, -5, 1, 3, 4, 50, -40, 10]})
```

Then, sum the values greater than 0 and less than 0.

```
positive_sum = df[df['value'] > 0]['value'].sum()
negative_sum = df[df['value'] < 0]['value'].sum()
```

And, print out the results.

```
print("positive: ", positive_sum)
print("negative: ", negative_sum)
```

Output

[image]